# How to check Excel cell's current format?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

How can I check a specific Excel cell's **current** format like bold & font color using VBA, when conditional formatting is applied? I know how to check the "base format", but how do I check the "current format"?

Comment: Tried function [IsCFMet](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html#isitmet) but it gave me "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" on line `sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlA1, xlR1C1)`.

Comment: [IsCFMet](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html#isitmet) seems to throw error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" on line `sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlA1, xlR1C1)` when your formula has ";" as argument separator (Finnish locale).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Range.DisplayFormat property set.

See:

[Range.DisplayFormat Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)